# Svelte reactivity - Class member change doesn't reflect on UI

Tags: javascript, web-component, svelte, custom-element

I'm currently creating a table manager web component which consists of a few different components, like `data-table`, `search-bar` etc. I manage it separately because there are cases when the table or search bar is not used, but when they're used together they use the same class as an input. The search bar calls one of the class's methods for search and it filters the data accordingly, and however the data property is changed in the class, it won't reflect on the UI only if I do some action to refresh is ( e.g. checking a checkbox ).

So I'm changing one member of a class by a class method call in component `A` and I want it to reflect in component `B`.

```
export let config: TableConfig = new TableConfig();
$: setConfig(config);

...

// Search function:
config.quickSearch(quickSearchValue);
```

I loop through the `config.data` to show some data. After the search, the `data` member changes and if I use a `setInterval` to log the config in the `table` component, it shows the changed `data` but the UI won't refresh.

Maybe my approach is completely wrong, but this is how I did it in Angular, but it had a lot of unnecessary dependencies, so now I'm trying to get rid of that.. So my main goal is to use this anywhere, like Svelte, Angular, VanillaJS etc.

#### EDIT:

REPL example: https://svelte.dev/repl/311538f2cf52484f8d0ac3aeae7540ea?version=3.31.0

Comment: If you are talking Svelte components then the tags ``web-component`` and ``custom-elements`` do not apply, those are for W3C Web Components.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on from your question. Can you show more of the component code where the issue occurs? It would also be helpful if you can make an example on the [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I'm creating web components in svelte, as I said I'm using them in Angular, Svelte and VanillaJS, I already made two packeges like this, but this will be a little bit bigger one

Comment: @GeoffRich Here is a repl example, I put a `setInterval` in `ComponentA` to log the config has changed after clicking the `Filter` button:
https://svelte.dev/repl/311538f2cf52484f8d0ac3aeae7540ea?version=3.31.0

Answer (score 1):

The UI does not change, because as far as Svelte knows there has been no change in data. You would have to add a subscription system to your class if you want to keep that structure.

Svelte however has a better approach for sharing data across components and that is [stores](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store). What you could do in your situation is create a custom store [enter link description here](https://svelte.dev/examples#custom-stores) that encapsulates the logic you used to have in a class. That way you can simply subscribe to this store in one component and trigger an update in another one, benefiting from Svelte's reactivity.

Comment: My main problem with stores with this particular example is that `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` will be two separate web components (one for filtering and one for the data visualization) and I want them to use the same data. ( And also I don't want to be restricted to svelte, I'd like to use it anywhere and I don't know if in this case stores would be a good solution )

Comment: I could use stores if I'd do something like fullcalendar does ( fullcalendar.io ), which is it creates a new `Calendar` object and passes the `div` as a parameter which will render the calendar: 
` var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar'); var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, { plugins: [ dayGridPlugin ]  }); calendar.render();`
And I could pass also component A and component B as well if needed, but I have no idea how to have it implemented like this ..

Comment: I think context (https://svelte.dev/tutorial/context-api) would make more sense than stores here, as the idea is to share data between a specific instance of a data-table/search-bar.

Comment: Yes, context is great, but the data-table won’t contain the search component, the point is that I can add the search to a dialog, a dropdown menu or above (or below) the data table. So there won’t be any parent-child relationship ( and if I understand correctly the context API is supposed to work like that ? )